# Custom EventHandler

Tags: c#

Is it a good practice to pass in a custom non EventArgs class to an EventHandler as such:

```
public event EventHandler<FooBar> FooBarCreated;
```

instead of

```
public event EventHandler<FooBarCreatedEventArgs> FooBarCreated;

public class FooBarCreatedEventArgs : EventArgs 
{
    ...

    public FooBar FooBar { get; }
}
```

The former is shorter but I seem to see the latter used in Microsoft's docs. Is the latter the proper way?

Comment: Do you have any links to the mentioned Microsoft docs or to your best practise source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Updated .NET Core Event Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/modern-events) documentation page states the following:

> The previous article discussed the most common event patterns. .NET Core has a more relaxed pattern. In this version, the EventHandler definition no longer has the constraint that TEventArgs must be a class derived from System.EventArgs.

Note, however, that if your class is designed to pass data to the event subscribers, you should still follow the naming convention and add the `Args` suffix (or `EventArgs` suffix if you derive from `EventArgs`).

You can, however, choose not to create a specific class just for event args, if all the data you want to to pass on to the event subscribers is a class you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the latter is preferred as it makes for more descriptive callback method signatures. E. G.

```cs
class FooBarEventObserver
{
   public void OnCreated(object sender, FooBarCreatedEventArgs args)
   {
     ....
   }
```